# Why do Dirac basis spinors stay invariant under the action of the parity operator

Tags: dirac-equation, parity

In Chapter 3.6, the Peskin & Schroeder define the action of the parity operator $P$ on the creation and annihilation operators as follows: $Pa^s_\mathbf{p}P = a^s_{-\mathbf{p}}$. The action of $P$ on the basis spinors of positive and negative frequencies $u(p)$ and $v(p)$ is not defined explicitly. However, when they apply the parity operator on the full wave function in equation 3.124, it is implied that $Pu(p)P = u(p)$ and $Pv(p)P = v(p)$. What I would have done is write $Pu(p)P = u(\tilde{p})$ (where $\tilde{p} = (p_0, -\mathbf{p})$ as defined in the book) and then the following change of variables in the integral becomes much easier, and there is no factor of $\gamma^0$ at the end. This is obviously wrong.

But I cannot justify $u$ and $v$ being invariant. Yes, the basis spinors are defined in the spinor space while the creation and annihilation operators are defined in the Fock space so in a sense it does make sense to me that the operator acting on one space might not act on another. But at the same time, the only formal way we have defined $P$ is that when at acts on *things* that depend on space $\mathbf{x}$ or spatial momentum $\mathbf{p}$, we simply change the sign of $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{p}$. In this spirit I am also assuming that $Pe^{i(p_0t-\mathbf{x}\mathbf{p})}P$ is also not actually invariant but it does remain invariant since both $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{p}$ change signs. This generic definition of the parity operator seems vague to me, hence why I can't justify the spinors remaining unchanged.

Comment: As you correctly say, $P$ is an operator in Fock space. As a consquence, it commutes with c-number objects like $u(p)$, $v(p)$ or $e^{\pm ip\cdot x}$. The action of a parity transformation on the field operator, $P \psi(t,\mathbf{x})P = \eta_a \gamma^0 \psi(t,-\mathbf{x})$ (c.f. eq. 3.126 in P.S.), is explained in full detail in your text book.